# c#. Get x that yields minimum of a parabola given by the equation y=a*x^2+b*x+c

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a method to find the number(integer) x for which the curve given by the equation `y (x) = ax ^ 2 + bx + c` gets the minimum value.

The method should take a non-negative coefficient `a`, as well as arbitrary coefficients `b` and `c`, and, if a solution exists, return a string representation of the desired `x`, and otherwise, the string "Impossible".

From math, equating the derivative to zero `y '(x) = 0`, it is easy to find the formula for the desired `x = - b / 2a`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetMinX
{
   class Program
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, 2, 3));
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 3, 2));
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, -2, -3));
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(5, 2, 1));
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(4, 3, 2));
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 4, 5));

         // in these cases the solution exists:
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) != "Impossible");
         Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) != "Impossible");
      }

      private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
      {
         var GetMinX = (double)(-b / ((2.0) * a));
         if (a > 0)
            GetMinX.ToString();
         else if (a == 0)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
         }
                  else
            GetMinX.ToString();
         return GetMinX.ToString();// this is how we output string representation of x value
      }

   }
}
```

As an output, I get the following:

```
-1
Invalid
-?
1
-0.2
-0.375
Invalid
-?
Invalid
True
Invalid
True
```

I provide 8 lines and get 12 answers. Can someone explain what's wrong in my code? Its functionally is incorrect, as it is.

Can this method be written using `?:` operator?

Comment: You probably want something like this: `return "a can not be equal to 0";` instead of `Console.WriteLine("Invalid");` You getting more results because in some cases (when a==0) your code prints "Invalid" and a number. Also you doing `!= "Impossible"` check but your method never returns "Impossible"....and you have to do a==0 check BEFORE you calculating, otherwise you will get an error - division by zero.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetMinX.ToString();` inside the method that often? Wouldn't it make more sense to say `if (a == 0) { return "Invalid"; }` (handle "special case" first) and then `var minX = (double)(-b / ((2.0) * a)); return minX.ToString();`. Btw. variables are usually named in lowerCaseCamelCase.

Comment: And not the same name as the method (to be less confusing).

Comment: `if (a > 0) GetMinX.ToString();` is just dead code. it won't do anything

Comment: As to your last question: sure... `return a == 0 ? "Invalid" : ((double)(-b / ((2.0) * a))).ToString();`... if you find that easier to read.

Comment: You never use `c`

Comment: `-b / (2 * a)` seems to determine the `y`-part of the minimum coordinate. While `c - (b * b / (4 * a))` determines the `x`-part.

Comment: ... or the other way 'round... >_< I'm just a developer, I don't know math...

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider *more cases* (**four**) than you've implemented:

```
1. a > 0 - min at -b / 2a
2. a < 0 - Invalid: no minimum, but maximum at -b / 2a
3. a = 0
     3.1 b = 0  - min at any x value (we have "y = c" equation)
     3.2 b <> 0 - Invalid: neither minimum nor maximum (we have "y = bx + c" equation)
```

**Implementation:**

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c) {
  if (a == 0) { // Degenerated case; we don't have parabola
    if (b != 0) // y is a straight line: y = b * x + c
      return "Invalid. Neither minumum nor maximum exists";
    else // y equals to c constant
      return $"Minimum {c} at any x"; 
  }
  else { // General case (parabola)
    double x = -b / (2.0 * a);
    double y = a * x * x + b * x + c;

    if (a < 0) // parabola with maximum value
      return $"Invalid. Minimum doesn't exist, but maximum {y} at {x}";
    else       // parabola with minimum value 
      return $"Minimum {y} at {x}";
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
private static void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, 2, 3));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 3, 2));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, -2, -3));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(5, 2, 1));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(4, 3, 2));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 4, 5));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2));
  Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0));
}
```

**Outcome:**

```
Minimum 2 at -1
Invalid. Neither minumum nor maximum exists
Minimum -4 at 1
Minimum 0.8 at -0.2
Minimum 1.4375 at -0.375
Invalid. Neither minumum nor maximum exists
Minimum 2 at any x
Minimum 0 at any x
```

Finally, you can well rewrite the routine with ternary operator `? :`, e.g.

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c) {
  return (a == 0) 
    ? // degenerated case
      b != 0 ? "Invalid" // straight line y = b * x + c 
             : "0"       // y == c; any x will do, let's put "0"
    : // general case
      a < 0  ? "Invalid" // parabola with maximum
             : (-b / (2.0 * a)).ToString(); // parabola with minimum
}
```

however, I don't think you should do it since this code is *less readable*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sir! I learned a lot from your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that formula is correct - I am missing c in it, lets say it is correct. Now your code should look something like this.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, 2, 3));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 3, 2));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, -2, -3));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(5, 2, 1));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(4, 3, 2));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 4, 5));

    // in these cases the solution exists:
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) != "Impossible");
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) != "Impossible");
}

private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
{
     //We can't proceed if a is zero otherwise we will get division by zero error
     if(a == 0)
        return "Invalid"; //Exit method with message. I would inform about mistake like "a variable is equal to zero"
     //Per requirement check if a is non negative - we can't do calculations then
     if(a < 0)
        return "Impossible"; //Exit method with message. Again I would use more informative message

    //all good do calculation and return result
    var minX = (double)(-b / ((2.0) * a));
    return minX.ToString();
}
```

Another thing. I would suggest not to focus to `?:` operator, `if else` statement is the equivalent. Start using `?:` when you completely understand the basics and you want to increase readability. `?:` is just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: I *think* the correct formula would be: `c - (b * b / (4 * a))`. If `a < 0`, there is no possible (meaningful) minimum (the parabola is opened downward; the formula would compute the maximum). And if `a == 0` it wouldn't be a parabola. So only `a > 0` would produce a valid minimum. -- The values of `b` and `c` can be whatever they want.

Comment: @Corak Thanks for your input, you might be right. As I wrote I am targeting on explaining code and your comment might lead OP to correct formula :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Now, I understand these basics better, with your explanations! However, I have the last question on this topic, regarding the last two input lines. Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) != "Impossible"); In that case the solution should exist. However, on that last check, I get an error. It should return True, but I get False... or vice versa... if I change Invalid with Impossible in your code...

Comment: @ShepenkovValeriy in both cases you passing `0` as `a` parameter, so it will always get to `a ==0` case and return "Invalid". So you always getting "Invalid" from method for both method calls and in both cases "Invalid" != "Impossible" is true. I am actually not sure what are you trying to do with those last 2 lines :)